# Is there a way to "kill" a Model Property?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My application's front end is a `DataGrid` whose contents are passed to an Excel-generating method.

The catch is that the DataGrid deals with 13 columns: 10 of them are fixed (i.e., passed to Excel) while each of the last 3 is optional.

```
public class GridModel
{
    public string Item          { get; set; }
    public string ItemName      { get; set; }
    public double TotalHeight   { get; set; }
    public double AGLheight     { get; set; }
    public double Embedment     { get; set; }
    public string Shape         { get; set; }
    public double TipDiameter   { get; set; }
    public double BaseDiameter  { get; set; }
    public double Taper         { get; set; }
    public double ShearReaction { get; set; }
    // The following are optional, in 8 combinations, from all present to all absent
    public double Camber        { get; set; }
    public double Rake          { get; set; }
    public double Angle         { get; set; }
}
```

Being a C# newbie, I am considering the different approaches.

How would you folks deal with this? The simplest idea that comes to mind is to add 3 flags to the model:

```
bool IsColumn1Present;
bool IsColumn2Present;
bool IsColumn3Present;
```

Another way would be to add a level to the hierarchy, so each of the 'special' columns contains its own embedded flag:

```
if (Camber.flag) add(Camber.value);
```

That said, I would like to have the ability to somehow **remove** those 3 properties, so any attempt to access them would result in an error or impossibility.

If such thing exists, I guess it would be called "Variant Properties".

TIA

Note: I have solved this already by the manipulation of the `Visibility.Visible` field at the GUI level. Gurus, however, tell us that this is a bad idea. Best practices dictate that this facility should be part of the Model.

Comment: Since they're optional, it makes sense to have business logic that interrogates something in order to determine visibility.  What are you using to determine visibility for these 3?  When they're greater than 0?

Comment: `What are you using to determine visibility for these 3?` Easy: if the user types anything at all in any of those 3 columns, that column is passed to the Excel-generating method. Any column which has been left pristine (untyped) becomes invisible. The GUI level is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use nullable properties:

```
public double? Camber { get; set; }
```

Then check them for a value in your business logic:

```
if (thing.Camber.HasValue)
{
    DoSomething(thing.Camber.Value);
}
```

It sounds like this might be exactly what you're after, given your comment on "variant" properties.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Update: If you need to switch them off application-wide (as per your comment), you could either avoid setting the value in the first place when it's not wanted (this would be preferable as this is, as far as I'm concerned, business logic and doesn't belong in your dumb model classes) or extend this with a custom accessor:

```
private double? _camber;

public double? Camber
{
    get
    {
        return ModelSettings.CamberEnabled
            ? _camber
            : null;
    }
    set;
}
```

Then have some static/constant property somewhere:

```
public static class ModelSettings
{
    public const bool CamberEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Does the `nullability` apply to a whole column (which is what I need), or to each specific row/value?

Comment: @TravisBanger Nope, that would be set per-object. If you need application-wide accessibility you could avoid setting the value in the first place when it's not wanted (preferable) or implement a custom accessor as per my edit.

Comment: "this would be preferable as this is, as far as I'm concerned, business logic and doesn't belong in your dumb model classes", I agree, I think making getters and setters in models do anything other than the default can lead to code bloat and coupling in places your don't want.

Comment: @akousmata Precisely my point - it may be the case, though, that it's a worthwhile tradeoff in this case. Hard to say without more knowledge of the application.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of columns is constant (meaning the user can't add 'custom' columns), I would suggest a bit-field `enum` value like so:

```
[Flags]
public enum ColumnFlags
{
    None = 0,
    Camber = 0x1,
    Rake = 0x2,
    Angle = 0x4,

    // Other optional columns here, keep them powers of 2!
}
```

Then in your `Model` class, keep a value such as:

```
public ColumnFlags ColumnFlags { get; set; }
```

Then you can use...

```
if(model.ColumnFlags.HasFlag(ColumnFlags.Camber))
{
  // Do something here...
}

if(model.ColumnFlags.HasFlag(ColumnFlags.Rake))
{
   // Do something here...
}
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, you can use the `Nullable<T>` types to specify a "missing" or "empty" value.